# Convert logic signals to be able to supply/sink higher currents

Tags: current, led-matrix, current-sink

I am making a LED matrix and have the required logic in place to drive the unit. My problem lies in the fact that my matrix is 80x56 diodes large and requires a fair amount of current. Each diode is rated at 20mA with a voltage drop of 2V across.

The screen is scrolling across the 56 columns, meaning that there are maximum 80 diodes lit at once. This translates to a potentioal power draw of 1.6 A. I have 10 8-bit latches representing the logical values of each lead across the displaying column. Is there a way i can draw current from an alternate source with the voltage values coming from the latches?

I have a possible solution consisting of connecting 80 voltage followers to each line but this approach seem very tedious.

This problem translates to the opposing axis where i have an array of demux chips outputting one logical low and 55 logical high at a time. Any way to sink 1.6 amps into the pin that is low?

Any input is appreciated :)

Comment: yes but more details are needed to say how

Comment: How many columns are you Muxing which implies LED peak current /20mA average.  Common LEDs are only 2or3:1 ABSMAX:Rated

Comment: How is making 80 voltage followers tedious after having to wire ~4500 LEDs in a matrix?

Comment: Out of interest, what did you go for in the end? Trevor made a good suggestion, as he usually does, but I thought the NCV7708 I recommended did everything you wanted with fewer components, fewer interconnects with SPI and more fault detection. Did the SPI make it unsuitable for your application or did you just prefer the TLC59213 and the discrete FETs for your own reasons? Just curious :-)

Comment: @TonyM I opted for Trevor's solution. I am currently waiting for the components to be delivered. I have however started soldering of the diodes. It is time consuming work, but i expect it to take no longer than the time I've put into the frame. The reason I did not want to apply your design was because of the slower performance. I am attempting to pwm the display through software and therefore need to be able to apply changes on the output at high frequencies. I am hoping to achieve roughly 50 intensities.

Comment: What speed are you scanning at, then, must be pretty high? It's not that my feelings are hurt, by the way :-) It just looks like a great IC and I've got applications lined up for it that I'm dying to find time for.

Comment: @TonyM Although the raspberry i am controlling the display with has SPI i don't know enough about its implementation to conclude whether or not it is faster than simply controlling the pins manually with the latch approach. Unless the SPI controller in the raspberry exhibit a significantly higher pin frequency than is achievable through manual control with c, I suspect it would limit my performance somewhat. I will try to update my question on completion of the project if i remember it. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @TonyM Although the raspberry i am controlling the display with has SPI i don't know enough about its implementation to conclude whether or not it is faster than simply controlling the pins manually with the latch approach. Unless the SPI controller in the raspberry exhibit a significantly higher pin frequency than is achievable through manual control with c, I suspect it would limit my performance somewhat. I will try to update my question on completion of the project if i remember it. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @TonyM Regarding the scanning speed i am unsure. The software i wrote included the maximum size matrix i could make with the leds i bought (20k min purchase). With a square matrix of 128*128 i reached 140 scans per second with 128 unique intesities. It will be a lot higher with the reduced size and fewer intensities

Comment: The limit will be the 5 MHz of the NVC7708. You need to send 14 of them 16 bits for every line, so 56 scan lines makes it 2.5 ms for the whole display. You set up the SPI controller to write out under continuous DMA and your CPU is completely free while your display is doing up to 400 refreshes/sec. You can do PWM for adjustable brightness and all sorts. Or you use parallel I/O and tie up the CPU with donkey work driving the display. Anyway, have fun with it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so you have two problems.

The 80 wide should be using something like the [TLC59213](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59213.pdf) 8-Bit Parallel In and Out Darlington Source Driver With Latch. That can source more current that you will ever need.
[image]
The other side, you pretty much need 56 drivers. Perhaps suitable mosfet at the end of each column.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4CZE7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Though you may not need the transistor in there if you use an open-collector output gate before that.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, this was exactly what i was looking for. I will replace my latches with TLC59213 drivers. I am however slightly confused by your suggestions on the column side. Will it work if i use N-channel mosfets between the end of each channel and ground? For instance this one: [link](http://no.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/IPU50R3K0CEBKMA1/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2fWi7%252b5d8ZJR2X7axcnlFZl8M4%3d) Can i drive the gate of this transistor from a 5v decoder IC? The gate threshold voltage is rated at 2.5V but i'm a noob so i figure it is wise to ask.

Comment: @MatsMeier, I did high side because the TLC59213 is a low side device.

Comment: @MatsMeier also my advice to you is. If the array is some distance from the controller, feed it a higher voltage and regulate locally.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Trevor. I will consider your suggestions moving forward and will likely implement your design in its entirety. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Trevor. I am close to finishing my project but have encountered an issue. In the datasheet of the driver you specified it says that the output current is negative. I assumed this meant that the device was sinking current. Coupled with you saying it was a low side driver i figured this was the case. Upon testing it seems that the driver won't sink current but only source it.

Now i have 56 mosfets applying 5v to the anodes of the diodes and the cathodes connected to the drivers. Will this not work in your opinion or is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I reckon this is more what i had in mind when designing the layout. [TLC59210](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59210.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array of the ONSemi NCV7708 hex H-bridge drivers. This contains 6 high-side drivers and 6 low-side drivers.

All 12 drivers are completely independent of each other. So 14 ICs would give you all of your high-side drivers and all of your low-side drivers. Each IC is about £2 each and you'd then just need series current-limiting resistors, assuming you're using them.

The IC interface is SPI up to 5 MHz and multiple devices can be daisy-chained so your final interface would be very simple, assuming you're coming from a suitable microcontroller.

The SPI interface lets you write each IC's driver levels and read its health status (over-current, over-temperature, under-load). I imagine you could use that to detect shorted-dead LEDs.

[image]